# Find large strings in files and show the files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

I would like to find large strings in a directory files and report them:

```
 awk 'length>50' /home/* -exec ls -l {} ';'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `find` for that, e.g:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Eq '.{50}' {} \; \
               -exec ls -l {} +
```

In GNU find `-exec ls -l {} +` could be replaced with just `-ls`.

And if long output is not necessary (requires GNU grep):

```
grep -Erl '.{50}' .
```

Comment: Great, it is giving all results in one line `strLen=$( grep -Erl '.{50}' /home/ ) echo $strLen >> $LOGFILE`

Comment: No it's not, you're misusing quotes when you call `echo`. Always quote your variables - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 3):

If your file names don't contain spaces then with POSIX tools:

```
grep -El '.{50}' /home/* | xargs ls -l
```

otherwise with GNU tools:

```
grep -ElZ '.{50}' /home/* | xargs -0 ls -l
```